# 2×2 squares inside a 9×9 square

Tags: mathematics

You are given an empty $9\times9$ grid (sort-of like a blank Sudoku grid,
or sort-of like a chessboard, but with one extra row and one extra column).
You fill in these cells randomly with all the integers between 1 and 81
(inclusive).
Prove that there is at least one $2\times2$ square
where the sum of the numbers is more than 137.

Comment: Sidenote: a chessboard has 8x8 squares

Comment: @fondor. I know...that's why i put chessboard in brackets. Just so people can visualize it better.

Comment: @fondor - see chessboard description; size and shape may be altered from the classical 8 by 8 square.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 4 corner squares are part of 1 2x2 square each, the 28 edge squares are part of 2 2x2 squares each, and the 49 center squares are part of 4 2x2 squares each.

> To minimize the sum of the 2x2 squares we put the higher numbers in the corners first and then at the edges, for a total sum of all 2x2 squares of 8774

The average of the 2x2 squares are then

> 8774/64=137.09375

Which proves it because

> not every 2x2 square can be smaller then this, so there must be some equal or higer, and since all numbers are integers, there must be a 2x2 square of at least 138.